# setuptools: data files included with `bdist` but not with `sdist`

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I've got a `setup.py` file which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        "": ["*"],
    },
)
```

And a package `foo` which looks like this:

```
foo/__init__.py
foo/bar.txt
```

When I run `setup.py bdist`, the `bar.txt` file is (correctly) included in the distribution… But when I use `setup.py sdist` it isn't.

What's up with that? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of `package_data`? Or is this a quirk of `setuptools`?

Answer (score 12):

There are different sources for selecting those files. The package_data is used for installing from the source tree. The build a source package you also need a MANIFEST.in file. It should contain something like `recursive-include *.txt`, or whatever you need.

Comment: Ah… So, under what circumstances would I ever use `package_data` then?

Comment: The manifest determines what is included in the source distribution, but the package_data is what is used to determine any data files that you want installed along with the source Python files in the package location (site-packages). Those files in MANIFEST.in may not docs or other files you don't want installed there, but do want in the source distribution.