# buildout incorrectly excluding non-python files from SOURCES.TXT

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

Recently I noticed that every develop egg I have in my dev buildout has an incorrect SOURCES.TXT file in the egg-info folder. It lists all of the python files, but ignores all of the XML, ZCML, etc. As far as I can tell, running "python setup.py bdist_egg" looks at this SOURCES.TXT file which results in a lot of missing files. I normally make a bdist_egg for anything ready for production, and store these in a repository that my production environment can pull from by specifying a version number.

I was able to see that running buildout is what generates this file (I also use mr.developer if that matters) but I can't find any more documentation. I don't know if it's a problem with my buildout config or setup.py for my package, or what. Here's the setup.py for a problem package for what it's worth:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

version = '1.23.1'

setup(name='ims.dermis',
  version=version,
  description="",
  # Get more strings from
  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=list_classifiers
  classifiers=[
    "Framework :: Plone",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
  keywords='',
  author='',
  author_email='',
  url='http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/',
  license='GPL',
  packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup']),
  namespace_packages=['ims'],
  include_package_data=True,
  zip_safe=False,
  install_requires=[
      'setuptools',
      # -*- Extra requirements: -*-
  ],
  entry_points="""
  # -*- Entry points: -*-

  [z3c.autoinclude.plugin]
  target = plone
  """,
  )
```

setuptools = 0.6c11
zc.buildout = 1.4.4

Comment: This is not a buildout problem, but a setuptools problem. Use a MANIFEST.in file to list what needs to be included in a binary dist.

Comment: See [setuptools: data files included with \`bdist\` but not with \`sdist\`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6714145)